# TDD with C#, issue with writing tests with mock

Tags: c#, unit-testing, tdd

I'm moving first steps in TDD (I'm studying "Professional Test-Driven Development with C#" by Bender and McWherter).

I'm trying to write my first application with TDD: I assume to have a DataService class for manage persistence. I wrote two tests that pass, but I think I've not got the point.

This is my first test, I assume that I can instantiate a Transaction, whatever it means in the DataService

```
public void Begin_a_transaction_should_returns_true_when_is_all_ok()
{
    Mock<IDataLayer> dataLayer = new Mock<IDataLayer>();
    DataService sut = new DataService(dataLayer.Object);

    bool expected = true;
    dataLayer.Setup(dl => dl.BeginTransaction()).Returns(expected);

    bool actual = sut.BeginTransaction();

    Assert.AreEqual(expected, actual);
}
```

According to TDD now I wrote the classes, no issues with this

```
public class DataService
{
    private IDataLayer _dataLayer;

    public DataService(IDataLayer dataLayer)
    {
        this._dataLayer = dataLayer;
    }

    public bool BeginTransaction()
    {
        return _dataLayer.BeginTransaction();
    }
}
```

Now I want to write second test: BeginTransaction should fail if transaction already exists, and I demand this to IDataLayer

```
[Test]
public void Begin_a_transaction_should_throws_exception_if_transaction_already_exists()
{
    Mock<IDataLayer> dataLayer = new Mock<IDataLayer>();
    DataService sut = new DataService(dataLayer.Object);

    dataLayer.Setup(dl => dl.BeginTransaction()).Throws(new Exception("Transaction already exists"));

    Assert.Throws<Exception>(() => sut.BeginTransaction());
}
```

And now the point: tests pass without writing any line of code, because I've mocked the BeginTransaction to throw an Exception.
That can be OK because I'll test it in the implementation of IDataLayer tests, but if I mock all, DataService tests are useful?

Comment: The DataService doesn't *do* anything, it's just a facade/proxy for the data layer, so the utility of unit testing it is likely to be quite low. Your two tests are effectively the same: given an injected data layer, calling the data service method calls a method on the data layer and returns the result.

Answer (score 1):

I would say this happens because you're testing the behavior of a class that does not have any behavior other than wrapping the `IDataLayer` - anything that happens in the wrapped class is simply passed on to the outside. The same thing that you are describing happens for the case when the method returns `true` although it's less obvious.

To make your example more meaningful you could add some behavior that is dependent on the result of IDataLayer's `BeginTransaction()`, like;

**Implementation**

```
public class DataService
{
    public DataService(IDataLayer dataLayer, IBookRepository bookRepository) 
    {
        _dataLayer = dataLayer;
        _bookRepository = bookRepository;
    }

    public void StoreBookInfo(string data)
    {
        if (_dataLayer.BeginTransaction())
            _bookRepository.StoreBookInfo(data);
        else
            throw new SomeException();
    }
}
```

**Test**

```
[Test]
public void Should_store_book_info_if_transaction_can_be_started()
{
    Mock<IDataLayer> dataLayer = new Mock<IDataLayer>();
    Mock<IBookRepository> bookRepository = new Mock<IBookRepository>();

    dataLayer.Setup(dl => dl.BeginTransaction()).Returns(true);
    bookRepository.Setup(x => x.StoreBookInfo(It.IsAny<string>()));

    DataService sut = new DataService(dataLayer.Object, bookRepository.Object);

    sut.StoreBookInfo("SomeValue");

    bookRepository.Verify(x => x.StoreBookInfo(It.IsAny<string>()));
}

[Test]
public void Should_throw_exception_if_transaction_cannot_be_started()
{
    Mock<IDataLayer> dataLayer = new Mock<IDataLayer>();
    Mock<IBookRepository> bookRepository = new Mock<IBookRepository>();

    dataLayer.Setup(dl => dl.BeginTransaction()).Returns(false);

    DataService sut = new DataService(dataLayer.Object, bookRepository.Object);

    Assert.Throws<SomeException>(() => sut.StoreBookInfo("someValue"));
}
```

Comment: Tnx. That's ok with TDD? Than, I'll have to write tests for implementation of IDataLayer?

Comment: Well, with TDD you're supposed to write tests for everything you implement (tests firsts, implementation after). I'll try to elaborate my answer with a better example :)

Answer (score 1):

Exposing internals just for the sake of tests generally is not good practice. In your case _transaction is made protected so that decorator could do changes to it's internal state. I'd better suggest to mimic behavior of a client.

```
    [Test]
    public void Begin_a_transaction_should_throws_exception_if_transaction_already_exists()
    {
        Mock<IDataLayer> dataLayer = new Mock<IDataLayer>();
        DataService sut = new DataService(dataLayer.Object);

        sut.BeginTransaction();

        Assert.Throws<Exception>(() => sut.BeginTransaction());
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, I reviewed my code in this way.

```
public class DataService
    {
        private IDataLayer _dataLayer;
        protected object _transaction;

        public DataService(IDataLayer dataLayer)
        {
            this._dataLayer = dataLayer;
        }

        public bool BeginTransaction()
        {
            if (_transaction != null)
                throw new Exception("Transaction already exists");

            _transaction = _dataLayer.BeginTransaction();

            return true;
        }
    }
```

Than I use a decorator pattern in test class

```
internal class DataServiceDecorator : DataService
        {
            public DataServiceDecorator(IDataLayer dataLayer) : base(dataLayer)
            { }

            public void InjectTransactionObject(object transaction)
            {
                this._transaction = transaction;
            }
        }
```

So I'm able to write this test

```
[Test]
        public void Begin_a_transaction_should_throws_exception_if_transaction_already_exists()
        {
            Mock<IDataLayer> dataLayer = new Mock<IDataLayer>();
            DataServiceDecorator sut = new DataServiceDecorator(dataLayer.Object);

            sut.InjectTransactionObject(new object());

            Assert.Throws<Exception>(() => sut.BeginTransaction());
        }
```

What do you think about this?